# Imagemagick (convert) error only when called from emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, imagemagick, elisp

I am trying to convert a pdf to png from Emacs using ImageMagick's `convert` tool.  I am using the following elisp command:

```
(call-process "convert" nil "test" t "/path/to/test.pdf" "/path/to/test.png")
```

which gives the results

```
convert: no images defined `/path/to/test.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3241.
```

However, if I run

```
$ convert test.pdf test.png
```

from a command terminal everything works fine and I get the correct png file.

Here is what I have tried:

- I confirmed that the path to `convert` is in the Emacs `exec-path` variable
- I tried starting Emacs with a clean .emacs
- I also checked that Ghostscript's `gs` is available (both from the terminal and a `call-process` because that seemed to cause a similar problem somewhere else I saw online

I am using Emacs 24.5 on Mac OSX (Yosemite), ImageMagick 6.9.2-10 installed via homebrew, and Ghostscript 9.07 installed via homebrew.

Any help will be appreciated.  BTW, the motivation to use `convert` from Emacs is so that I can get Latex (tikz) figure blocks exported from org-mode/org-babel (which use a nearly identical `call-process` command), so I really need to get this to work "as is" rather than a work around.  Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is a path related issue and I've seen it before, but I don't remember what path is missing.  I'll think about it.  In the meantime, consider evaluating the **$PATH** in the buffer you are working in:  `M-x eval-expression RET (getenv "PATH") RET`  It's not the path were `convert` is, but another path that `convert` relies upon.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!  The `convert` path was in `exec-path` but not the path returned by (getenv "PATH"), so I added `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin"))` to .emacs and now it works (where /usr/local/bin contains both `convert` _and_ `gs`).  What does (getenv "PATH") return?  Obviously the the `convert` path is in my shell PATH variable...

Comment: `(getenv "PATH")` should return value of the path used by Emacs.  Emacs doesn't (by default) use the same path that is returned in let's say Terminal.app. There is a popular library that some people use (but I've never tried) -- https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell -- to set Emacs to the system-wide path.  I like to set it on a buffer local basis with:  `(set (make-local-variable 'process-environment) (mapcar 'concat process-environment)) (setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin"))` -- e.g., when I am in my custom tex mode.

Comment: Just a clarification: exec-path-from-shell doesn't take the "system-wide path" and use it in Emacs.  Emacs normally uses the "system-wide path" and Terminal.app is the exception where you get some other $PATH (because the corresponding setting is in your `~/.bashrc` or something like that), and exec-path-from-shell then tries to extract this $PATH you get in your terminal and tell Emacs to use it.  The better solution is to move your $PATH setting from your `~/.bashrc` to some other place where it does affect the system-wide setting (e.g. `~/.something/environment.plist` if that still works).

Answer (score 0):

I normally will use emacs command shell-commando (M-!) or M-x shell-command and then convert /path/to/pdf.pdf /path/to/pdf.png. Normally It should work better with existing directories
Or if you want to use wiht emacs lisp I opened the directory with emacs, inside a buffer, then execute ielm on that buffer.

For executing this commands, I also recommend you to use the function shell-command. this is the ouput in ielm and messages:

```
ELISP> (shell-command "ls")
0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)
ELISP> (shell-command "ls")
0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)
ELISP> (shell-command "convert pdf.pdf pdf.png")
0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)
ELISP> (shell-command "ls")
0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)
ELISP> (shell-command "pwd")
0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)
```

[image]

If tuou want to use call-process the correct syntax wiill be:

```
ELISP> (call-process "convert" nil t nil "pdf.pdf" "pdf.png")
```